# Genesis.json permanence and updating the blockchain

Tags: blockchain, gas-limit, genesis

I understand that the initial `genesis.json` attributes are a permanent thing, and it cannot be changed retroactively.

But what I want to know is which parameters are changeable afterwards and how?

- Could I change the `gasLimit` afterwards somehow? By using an account/key with the right rights?
- Could the difficulty be changed afterwards?
  And which params can't be changed (I'm guessing alloc is only a genesis param?)

Or am I misunderstanding, and can every block afterwards have their own `gasLimit`?

- And finally, what happens when you want to update/upgrade your blockchain?